# Mapping Tuple Dictionary to Multiple columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Ive got a PDB DataFrame with residue insertion codes. Simplified example.

```
d = {'ATOM' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
    'residue_number' : [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
    'insertion' : ['', '', '', '', '', '', 'A', 'A', 'A', '', '', '']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Dataframe:

```
    ATOM  residue_number insertion
0      1               2          
1      2               2          
2      3               2          
3      4               3          
4      5               3          
5      6               3          
6      7               3     A
7      8               3     A
8      9               3     A
9     10               5          
10    11               5          
11    12               5
```

I need to renumber the residues according to a different numbering and insertion scheme. Output from the renumbering script can be formatted into a dictionary of tuples, e.g.

```
my_dict = {(2,): 1, (3,): 2, (3, 'A') : 3, (5, ) : (4, 'A') }
```

Is it possible to map this dictionary of tuples onto the two columns ['ATOM']['insertion']? The desired output would be:

```
    ATOM  residue_number insertion
0      1               1          
1      2               1          
2      3               1          
3      4               2          
4      5               2          
5      6               2          
6      7               3         
7      8               3         
8      9               3         
9     10               4      A          
10    11               4      A          
11    12               4      A
```

I've been searching and banging my head on this for a few days, I've tried mapping and multindex but cant seem to find a way to map a dictionary of tuples across multiple columns. I feel like I'm thinking about it wrong somehow. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Man that `dict` is a pain to get into a DataFrame with a mix of tuples and integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic here is a simple merge. But we need to do a lot of work to turn that dictionary into a suitable DataFrame for mapping. I'd reconsider whether you can store the renumbering output as my final `s` DataFrame from the start.

```
#Turn the dict into a mapping
s = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values())[0].explode().to_frame()
s['idx'] = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
s = (s.pivot(columns='idx', values=0)
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1) 
     .rename(columns={0: 'new_res', 1: 'new_ins'}))

s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([*my_dict.keys()], names=['residue_number', 'insertion'])

s = s.reset_index().fillna('')  # Because you have '' not NaN
#   residue_number insertion  new_res new_ins
#0               2                  1        
#1               3                  2        
#2               3         A        3        
#3               5                  4       A
```

The mapping is now a merge. I'll leave all columns in for clarity of the logic, but you can use the commented out code to drop the original columns and rename the new columns.

```
df = df.merge(s, how='left')

# Your real output with 
#df = (df.merge(s, how='left')
#        .drop(columns=['residue_number', 'insertion'])
#        .rename(columns={'new_res': 'residue_number',
#                         'new_ins': 'insertion'}))
```

---

```
    ATOM  residue_number insertion  new_res new_ins
0      1               2                  1        
1      2               2                  1        
2      3               2                  1        
3      4               3                  2        
4      5               3                  2        
5      6               3                  2        
6      7               3         A        3        
7      8               3         A        3        
8      9               3         A        3        
9     10               5                  4       A
10    11               5                  4       A
11    12               5                  4       A
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, after reading this I went back to the renumbering program and wrangled the output to look like the s dataframe above. Then the merge  worked as advertised. I guess it was not obvious that merging DataFrames with different sizes "maps" the values by filling them in? Im still a little confused as how this works.

Comment: @Drewaight because your renumbering table is unique with respect to the merge keys the merge is just a **Many-to-one** mapping of the old (residue, insertion) to the new (residue, insertion). And likely you have every original (residue, insertion) in that table so it wont decrease the size (you can add how='left') so that it never drops any rows. Basically it's like mapping the tuples, but making tuples gets slow in `pandas` so a 2-column merge is often a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can create a `DataFrame` with your dictionary after modifying it to **set all values ​​as tuples**. So we can use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or . I think this is easier(
and **recommended**) if we convert the **blank values** ​​of the `insertion` column to `NaN`.

```
import numpy as np
new_df = ( df.assign(insertion = df['insertion'].replace(r'^\s*$',
                                                         np.nan,
                                                         regex=True)
                                                .mask(df['insertion'].isnull()))
              .join(pd.DataFrame({x:(y if isinstance(y,tuple) else (y,np.nan))
                                  for x,y in my_dict.items()},
                                  index = ['new_residue_number','new_insertion']).T,
                     on = ['residue_number','insertion'])
              .fillna('')
              .drop(['residue_number','insertion'],axis=1)
              .rename(columns = {'new_residue_number':'residue_number',
                                 'new_insertion':'insertion'}))
print(new_df)
    ATOM  residue_number insertion
0      1             1.0          
1      2             1.0          
2      3             1.0          
3      4             2.0          
4      5             2.0          
5      6             2.0          
6      7             3.0          
7      8             3.0          
8      9             3.0          
9     10             4.0         A
10    11             4.0         A
11    12             4.0         A
```

**Detail**

```
print(pd.DataFrame({x:(y if isinstance(y,tuple) else (y,np.nan))
                    for x,y in my_dict.items()},
                   index = ['new_residue_number','new_insertion']).T)
      new_residue_number new_insertion
2 NaN                  1           NaN
3 NaN                  2           NaN
  A                    3           NaN
5 NaN                  4             A
```

---

Answer (score 1):

in this case I think that you need to define a function that gets as input your old `residue_number` and `insertion` and outputs the new ones. For that, I will work directly from the df, so, to avoid extra coding, I will redefine your `my_dict` from `(2,)` to this `(2,'')`

here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ATOM' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
    'residue_number' : [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
    'insertion' : ['', '', '', '', '', '', 'A', 'A', 'A', '', '', '']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

# Our new dict with keys and values as tuples
my_new_dict = {(2,''): (1,''), (3,''): (2,''), (3,'A'): (3,''), (5,''): (4,'A') }

# We need a function that maps a tuple (residue_number, insertion) into your new_residue_number and new_insertion values
def new_residue_number(residue_number, insertion, my_new_dict):
    # keys are tuples
    key = (residue_number, insertion)
    # Return new residue_number and insertion values
    return my_new_dict[key]

# Example to see how this works
print(new_residue_number(2, '', my_new_dict)) # Output (1,'')
print(new_residue_number(5, '', my_new_dict)) # Output (4, 'A')
print(new_residue_number(3, 'A', my_new_dict)) # Output (3,'')

# Now we apply this to our df and save it in the same df in two new columns
df[['new_residue_number','new_insertion']] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(new_residue_number(row['residue_number'], row['insertion'], my_new_dict)), axis=1)
```

[image: output here]

I hope this can solve your problem!